# Found: rotted conduit main power supply into house

Tags: electrical

Was digging out my final gate post hole and realized that the conduit carrying the main power supply into the house was corroded through. The cable sheathing does not appear to be compromised. I'm wondering what I am in for regarding repairs and cost... sheesh.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

It will not be cheap and it cannot be ignored. But if it is between the utility pole / vault and your meter, it might be their (the utility's) responsibility. That varies from place to place, but it certainly can't hurt to call them.

Comment: called the local power company and they sent a guy out within 60 minutes... he says nothing to worry about. the insulated power cables are intended to be direct buried and as long as the individual wire 8nsulati8n hasn't been compromised, then nothing to worry about.

Comment: Make sure you direct bury it with a few inches of sand or sifted soil first... You're not allowed to let rocky soil come into contact with wires.

Comment: you could slit a 4" plastic conduit and wrap that round if you want to cover it up but it's anyones guess if the rest of that conduit is intact